# How to Prevent the TransformXml build task replacing line breaks?

Tags: configuration, msbuild, web-config, transformation

I am using the following in my project files:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="Exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
    <!--Generate transformed app config in the intermediate directory-->
    <TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
    <!--Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on.-->
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

However, if I have a config item on multi-lines

```
<add key="MultiLine" value="option1,
    option2,
    option3 />
```

It gets transformed to

```
 <add key="MultiLine" value="&#xD;&#xA;         option1,&#xD;&#xA;          option2,&#xD;&#xA;         option3/>
```

How can I prevent that?

Thank you

Ryan